# Ruby - Merge an Array into a Hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array which looks like this:

```
array = [[:foo, :bar], [:foo, :baz], [:baz, {a: 1, b: 2}], [:baz, {c: 1, d:2}]]
```

and I need to turn it into a hash which looks like this:

```
{:foo =>[:bar, :baz], :baz => {a: 1, b: 2, c: 1, d: 2}}
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
def flatten(array)
  h = {}
  array.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), memo|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      memo[k] = h.merge!(v)
    else
      # What goes here?
    end
  end
end
```

When used like so:

```
flatten(array)
```

outputs:

```
{baz => {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 1, :d => 2}}
```

May someone please point me in the right direction?  Help appreciated.

Comment: Wow that's such an inconsistent transformation. You perform different unification operations depending on the types. What if `array = [[:foo, {:a => 1}], [:foo, :bar]]`?

Comment: Your sample code does not compile: for example, list and memo are undefined. Please paste the code you actually tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def convert(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |a,h|
    h[a.first] =        
      case a.last
      when Hash
        (h[a.first] || {}).update(a.last)
      else
        (h[a.first] || []) << a.last
      end
  end
end

convert array
  #=> {:foo=>[:bar, :baz], :baz=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>1, :d=>2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[ array.group_by(&:first).map{ |k,a| [k,a.map(&:last)] } ]
```

Comment: you were right @kirill. i removed my answer actually. bcoz my approach was changed and becomes similar to Cary. but thanks.. i didnt notice that difference... Thanks.

Comment: Output of this answer is not same as the one expected by OP

Comment: @WandMaker, I figured out after posting. And that was mentioned already (comment is removed).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at solving this problem.  I have to make assumption that in the input array, entries like the ones similar to `:baz` will always be paired with `Hash` objects.  The solution will not work if you have one `:baz` with a symbol and another with hash.

```
array = [[:foo, :bar], [:foo, :baz], [:baz, {a: 1, b: 2}], [:baz, {c: 1, d:2}]]

h = Hash.new
array.each do |n1, n2|
    if n2.class == Hash
      h[n1] = (h[n1] || {}).merge(n2) 
    else
      h[n1] = (h[n1] || []) << n2
    end
end
p h
```

**Output**

```
{:foo=>[:bar, :baz], :baz=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>1, :d=>2}}
[Finished in 0.1s]
```